# Error while compiling Quipper 0.7

Tags: haskell

I have tried to build the Quipper quantum programming language by Dr Selinger but I found this error in Haskell that I don't understand.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make SUBDIR_TARGET=all  quipper Libraries QuipperLib Algorithms/BF Algorithms/BWT Algorithms/CL Algorithms/GSE Algorithms/QLS Algorithms/TF Algorithms/USV Programs/QCLParser Programs/Tools tests tests/template
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -C "Libraries" all
cd /private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7; "/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7/quipper/scripts/quipper" -O -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-K50m -i"/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7/quipper" -i"/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7" -fwarn-incomplete-patterns -Werror Libraries/Auxiliary.hs && touch -c Libraries/Auxiliary.hi
[1 of 1] Compiling Libraries.Auxiliary ( Libraries/Auxiliary.hs, Libraries/Auxiliary.o )
cd /private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7; "/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7/quipper/scripts/quipper" -O -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-K50m -i"/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7/quipper" -i"/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7" -fwarn-incomplete-patterns -Werror Libraries/CommandLine.hs && touch -c Libraries/CommandLine.hi
[2 of 2] Compiling Libraries.CommandLine ( Libraries/CommandLine.hs, Libraries/CommandLine.o )
cd /private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7; "/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7/quipper/scripts/quipper" -O -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-K50m -i"/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7/quipper" -i"/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7" -fwarn-incomplete-patterns -Werror Libraries/PortableSignals.hs && touch -c Libraries/PortableSignals.hi
[1 of 1] Compiling Libraries.PortableSignals ( Libraries/PortableSignals.hs, Libraries/PortableSignals.o )
cd /private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7; "/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7/quipper/scripts/quipper" -O -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-K50m -i"/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7/quipper" -i"/private/var/.home/admin/Documents/code/quipper-0.7" -fwarn-incomplete-patterns -Werror Libraries/RandomSource.hs && touch -c Libraries/RandomSource.hi

Libraries/RandomSource.hs:17:8:
    Could not find module ‘System.Random’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
make[2]: *** [RandomSource.hi] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Libraries] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally resolved it by

```
sudo apt-get install cabal-install 
cabal update
```

then I was able to install the random package with

```
cabal install random
```